# Динамический вывод значения input в теле сайта

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

Добрый день.
Есть много инпутов, которые сгенерированы системой.
Мне нужно отдельно в теле сайта выводить значение инпутов.

[image: человек нажимает на качельки и знечения изменяются]

[image: код инпута]

так как система генерирует автоматом (плагин), то я привязался к имени и вытянул значение в div блок, но оно у меня не меняется динамически, когда человек нажимает на качельки.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) 
 {
  
 var value_input = $("input[name*='product-options[1271][58]']").val(); 
 $("#for_my_script").append("<p>" + value_input + "</p>") 
 
});
</script>
```

буду благодарен за помощь.
спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В даном случае запись значений происходит при событии document.ready(), тоесть при загрузке DOM.

Для того чтобы значения в div'е "for_my_script" менялись автоматически, Вам нужно повесить событие именно на кнопки качелек.

Можете создать функцию и вызывать ее каждый раз когда происходит нажатие на качельку.

```
function RefreshDiv(){
var value_input = $("input[name*='product-options[1271][58]']").val(); 
    $("#for_my_script").html("<p>" + value_input + "</p>")  
}
```

Также можете вызывать ее (если нужно) при document.ready():

```
jQuery(document).ready(function{    
RefreshDiv();   
});
```

Comment: извините за тупость но я никакой в jq.
отсюда и вопрос - как привязять к качелькам? и взять во внимание что их єсть 2 для одного инпута, а вот инпутов есть 20 штук

Comment: Как вариант, просто привязываетесь к классу кнопок "ui-spinner-button":
`$('.ui-spinner-button').click(function(){
RefreshDiv(); 
});`

Answer (score 1):

Используйте вместо jQuery(document).ready(function($) событие change

```
$("input[name*='product-options[1271][58]']").change(function() {
    var value_input = $("input[name*='product-options[1271][58]']").val(); 
    $("#for_my_script").append("<p>" + value_input + "</p>")    

}
```

Comment: попробовал. заменил свой код на ваш.
изменений нет.
в моем при загрузке вытягивает значение (0 по умолчанию) не не меняет при смене.
после смены  - ничево не происходит и значения нет. даже по умолчанию которого.
сори за тупость, я плох в js

Comment: Этот код надо вставить после хтмл кода, либо внутрь вашего jQuery(document).ready(function{ ... }